# Serial read doesnt loop well

Tags: arrays, arduino, serial-port

it's hard to dertermine a appropriate question for my problem, so hear is what i want:
I have an Arduino Pro Micro and an Arduino Nano 33 BLE. The Nano use his 9axis Sensor to get the Position. I only use the angle of up/down and left/right. He map the angles betwen 21 to 108 and 0 to 100 for a pitch and a volume. I write the Numbers via sprintf in an char array and send it via Serial 1 to the Arduino Pro Micro.

Here i have the Problem. I want to read permanently the sended Array. I use this atm:

```
void readURAT(){
  
  char buffer[7], inChar;
  int i =0;
  
  while(Serial1.available() > 0){
    if(i<index){
      inChar=Serial1.read();
      buffer[i]=inChar;
      i++;
    }else{
      buffer[6]='\0';
      i=0;
      Serial.println(buffer);
      Serial1.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

This works but only a few times. It's like, i get the value 10 times and then nothing. The Char Value is for example "066070". Doe's someone have a clue what i missed?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If Serial1 does not have a complete message available, you probably run out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an silent buffer overflow because you loop var `i` is not checked against the array size (7) of `buffer`. `index` is not defined in the function.

if you receive less then `index` char, your buffer will not have a `\0` terminator.